# How to change the CSS style on required form inputs based on their values

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to know how to write the javascript to alter the style of form elements which are required; and change them if they have values in them.

What I want to do is have a colored border around the required text fields when they are blank, and remove the border style when they have values.

what I've thought of doing is to write a single javascript function which checks if the value is empty and set the appropriate style:

```
function requiredElement(id) {
  var Input = document.getElementById(id);
  if(Input.value==null) {
    Input.style.border = '2px solid #FF0000';
  }
}
```

But what I'm stuck with is changing the style as user enters/removes characters in these required fields, and calling the function for the fields.

I have a simple html form, each input has a unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then add this code:

```
$('.important').change(function() {
  if(($(this).val()) != '') $(this).css( 'border-width', '0' );
  else  $(this).css( 'border-width', '2' );
});
```

Assuming you added a border in the css

```
.important
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine when the element's value changes, bind your custom function to the `onchange` and `onkeypress` events (or, in jQuery, bind to [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)).

To actually change the appearance of the element, It's best to define styles in a CSS class and use JavaScript to add/remove the class as appropriate.

You can change an HTML element's CSS classes through JavaScript like this:

```
element = document.getElementById("myElement");
element.className = "invalid";
```

Or, in jQuery, use the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function:

```
$("#myElement").addClass("invalid");
```

---

HTML:

```
<input id="something" name="something" type="text" class="inputClass"
    onchange="requireElement(this)"
    onkeypress="requireElement(this)" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function requireElement(element) {
    if(element.value == null)
        element.className = "inputClass invalid";
    else
        element.className = "inputClass";
}
```