# How to change default styles for IE required elements?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-10, required

IE 10 is giving me undesired UI for `input` elements that include a `required` attribute. For type=text, it’s a tooltip and for checkboxes, a red border.

I’ve figured out how to prevent such things in Chrome and Firefox (via pseudo-selectors). Are there selectors for these in IE, or other methods?

[image]

Comment: Here is you answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609737/how-to-change-the-css-style-on-required-form-inputs-based-on-their-values

Enjoy !

Answer (score 5):

What looks like red border seems to be just an outline, which can be modified or removed using `outline` properties in CSS, e.g. set to one pixel wide using `outline-width: 1px` or removed using `outline: none`.

The tooltips might be something that you cannot style. Note that there are two kinds of tooltips for a required field on IE: one that you get on mouseover (a small simple box), and one that you get when trying to submit the form without a value for the required field (a larger box with a little arrow-like part, as in the screenshot).

Comment: `outline: none` fixed the problem in IE10